# ArangoDB prompts to enter the root password despite the authentication is disabled in the command line

Tags: docker, dockerfile, arangodb

I'd like to include and launch ArangoDB as a part of an Ubuntu docker image but I receive a prompt to enter the root's password when the following command is issued:

```
RUN sudo arangod --server.authentication false --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8529 --database.directory standalone &
```

`--server.authentication false` must disable ArangoDB's authentication per my understanding, but why does the image building process stop to enter the root's password? How to fix this issue so that the database would have `root` username without a password?